# CMDExec if exists then stop

Tags: file, powershell, cmd, exists, sql-job

I need to have step in SQL Job to check is there file on some path, so if there is file then stop with further execution. Something like:

```
$file = "\\networklocation\file.bak"
if (-exists (Test-Path $file)) 
{
    throw "$file not found."
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the `-exists` switch and ensure the `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to `stop`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
$file = "\\networklocation\file.bak"
if (Test-Path $file) 
{
    throw "$file found."
}
```

Comment: Er... I think he wants to stop if the file does exist.

Comment: @WalterMitty You are right. Will edit my answer - just wondering why he throws an exception if the file doesn't exists (thats actual the state he is expecting)...

Comment: Well, to explain it. There is some backup/restore job which work on the mechanism: 1. take backup from prod 2.restore it on office zone 3. delete backup file that can be done again on user request. Not my logic guys

Answer (score 0):

Test-Path cmdlet return Boolean and you are almost there:

```
$file = "\\networklocation\file.bak"
if (Test-Path $file)
{
    throw "$file not found."
}
```